# How to make the back to pagination button go back to previous pagination page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I have added a `Back To Gallery` button which appears in the image showcase page for a photography website gallery.

However when the button is clicked it goes back to the pagination's first page, I would like the button to direct the user back to the previous pagination page when clicked.

As an example if the image clicked was in pagination number 22 when the image is clicked and after user views the image and want to go back the button has to take the user back to pagination 22 not going back to pagination 1.

Answer (score 0):

With php you can relocate a user with

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` stands for de user his previous page

With javascript you can relocate a user with

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>go back
</a>
```

Comment: i need the button to redirect to the previous pagination.

Comment: you can easy do that with javascript, with `window.history.back();`

Comment: i had problems with the snippet but i was able to use this one for that snip wasnt compatible with all browser even on mobile

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i>go back</a>